# Imports for Datastax QueryBuilder to avoid QueryBuilder.eq in scala

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

When looking at examples for the Datastax Cassandra Driver, `where` clauses usually end up like this:

```
val select = QueryBuilder.select()
  .all()
  .from("addressbook", "contact")
  .where(eq("type", "Friend"))
```

but when I attempt this in scala i get this error:

```
Error:(25, 75) type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean
 required: com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Clause
```

To get it to work I always have to prefix the `eq` with `QueryBuilder.eq` to get it to work:

```
val select = QueryBuilder.select()
  .all()
  .from("addressbook", "contact")
  .where(QueryBuilder.eq("type", "Friend"))
```

I tried importing `QueryBuilder._`, since `eq` is a static method on it, but that didn't help. What setup am i missing to use the more concise form from the example?

Comment: what error do you get if you try using `eq` without a prefix?

Comment: You should only be able to call the static method without a prefix when you are inside the class (scope wise). Can you check what the value of 'this' is when you're inside the where?

Comment: Added the error above. Seems like somehow eq is imported from somewhere, but i don't have any imports other than DataStax related things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eq` is a standard Scala method defined on `AnyRef` (it's to Scala what `==` is to Java). The non-prefixed version is probably resolved to a call to `eq` on the object enclosing your statement definition.

One thing you can do is rename your import:

```
import QueryBuilder.{eq => equ} // TODO find a better name :-)
```

We could even provide a built-in alias with the driver, as I imagine others will run into this.

If there's a cleaner solution I'd be interested to know it.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. So this an unfortunate conflict with default scala imports.